# How is Lang implicit parameter resolved in Play

Tags: scala, playframework, internationalization, implicit

I have a controller like this

```
def index = Action.async { implicit request =>
implicit val lang = Lang(Language.mapping.lift(request.queryString("country").head).getOrElse("en"))
  ///...
  futureResult.map{...}
  .recover {
      case error =>
        displayError(error)
    }
}

private def displayError(throwable: Throwable)(implicit lang: Lang) = {
    throwable match {     
      case error: NotFoundException => Status(404)(views.html.errors.notFound("resource.notfound"))
   //...
  }
}
```

And an error template :

```
@(message: String)(implicit lang: Lang)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<p>@Html(Messages(message))</p>
...
```

I've noticed a few things :

- If `val lang = ...` is not defined as implicit, compile is still working, I can call `displayError` method
- If you don't pass lang explicitly to the displayError like this : `displayError(error)(lang)`, the value passed to the private method is not the one defined by my code, but the last one used by my browser (I guess in a cookie?)

So looking at the code it seems to be a simple private method call, but is Play doing some implicit values modifications before each method call, even private ones, even without passing through the router ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Play `2.3.x` documents (refer to [this page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaI18N) for more info):

> Note: If you have an implicit Request in the scope, it will provide an implicit Lang value corresponding to the preferred language extracted from the Accept-Language header and matching one of the application supported languages. You should add a Lang implicit parameter to your template like this: @()(implicit lang: Lang).

So this happens because you have an `implicit` request in your scope. Yes, even for `private` methods, provided that your private method accepts lang as an `implicit` parameter, because `implicit` parameters will be transitively available.

If you don't want this behavior either remove the `implicit` from request parameter or provide your own language explicitly which is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not thinking of the implicit request parameter.

Comment: Something I still find strange is that my implicit lang is defined after the implicit request. If I println my lang at the end of `index` the value is good, but at the beginning of `displayError` it's wrong

Comment: No worries. This is actually an implicit conversion from `Request` to `Lang`. It is the trickiest kind of implicit conversion because the subject to conversion is `implicit` itself! So it's an implicit conversion of an implicit parameter :)

Comment: What do you mean by wrong? Is it different or non-existing or ..? If you want to provide your own lang better to pass it explicitly to your methods for debugging purpose. Then you will find a good place to put it and use it in all controllers later.

Comment: By wrong I mean, the lang of the browser, not the lang I've defined in  my implicit val lang. I just don't get why my implicit value does not override the implicit provided with the request (by implicit conversion) when I call my private method. Is there a way to force the overriding, other than explicit passing?

Comment: Of course you can remove `implicit` keyword from request. Then the only implicit `Lang` in your context will be the one you provide. For a better understanding of where Scala looks for implicits refer to [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits).